# Angular component jenkins build issue for 'auto' css property

Tags: css, angular

In template file for angular component, I am using 'auto' css property with ngStyle, as:

```
'height' : (some_condition) ? '16px' : auto
```

Component works as epxected.

But in jenkins build, I get error as:

> Property 'auto' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'.

What's the reason for this error?And how can to get rid of it?

Comment: wrap auto in quotes `"auto"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not single quotes `'` around `auto` is what causes the issue.

Angular thinks `auto` is a variable in your component because you're setting the property of your DOM element via binding, which sort of expects something like this: `[property]=yourVariable`.

To fix it, you can either have a variable in your component that holds the string `"auto"` or you can simply type `'auto'`, with single quotes, in your template.

Also, when serving your app, try using the --aot flag (`ng serve --aot`). Doing so should prompt you with the same error you get with Jenkins but you won't have to actually build.
This flag is great and should always be used when possible in my opinion.